# JButton appearance as if it were pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

In some cases a need my JButton to appear as if it were pressed. This depends on some boolean.
I tried to create my own ButtonModel that overrides the default `isPressed()` method but in that way the button appears pressed only in case the mouse pointer is on top of it (without pressing a mouse button). I need it to appear pressed also if the mouse is somewhere else.

So far I tried this:

```
class MyButtonModel extends DefaultButtonModel
{
  private boolean appearPressed;

  @Override
  public boolean isPressed()
  {
    return super.isPressed() || appearPressed;
  }
}
```

I cannot use a `JToggleButton` or something similar.
My button derives from another class that implements some additional features and derives itself from `JButton`.

UPDATE:
I'm running on Windows 10 and use the WindowsClassic Look&Feel.

Comment: I believe you need a combination of "armed", "selected" and "pressed" to be true to have the button painted in a pressed state. Don't remember if you need all 3 or two of the 3.

Comment: judging by your self-answer, the required behavior is not fully specified here .. you might consider improving the description :) Depending on your _exact_ requirement, overriding the buttonModel might not be the best approach: if you want to change the appearance only (all behaviour the same, like OS specifics on when/how to trigger an action) solving it with a custom UI might be cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial reply was given by **@Philipp Li** and **@camickr**. Thank you.
My button model needs to override `isArmed()` in order to obtain the desired result.

However, once the button is pressed, it doesn't respond anymore.
Digging in the source of `DefaultButtonModel`, I found this:

```
public void setPressed(boolean b)
{
  if ((isPressed() == b) || (!isEnabled()))
    return;
  ...
}
```

This method is invoked by `AbstractButton.doClick()` in order to notify the various ActionListeners.
In other words, if the overridden method `isPressed()` returns true because I want to make the button appear pressed, a successive click on that button will be ignored.
A similar thing occurs within `DefaultButtonModel.setArmed()`.

Therefore, I implemented my button model as follows:

```
class MyButtonModel extends DefaultButtonModel
{
  boolean appearPressed = false;

  private boolean withinSetPressedMethod = false;

  private boolean withinSetArmedMethod = false;

  @Override
  public void setPressed(boolean pressed)
  {
    withinSetPressedMethod = true;
    super.setPressed(pressed);
    withinSetPressedMethod = false;
  }

  @Override
  public void setArmed(boolean armed)
  {
    withinSetArmedMethod = true;
    super.setArmed(armed);
    withinSetArmedMethod = false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isPressed()
  {
    if (withinSetPressedMethod)
      return (super.isPressed());
    else
      return (super.isPressed() || appearPressed);
  }
  
  @Override
  public boolean isArmed()
  {
    if (withinSetArmedMethod)
      return (super.isArmed());
    else
      return (super.isArmed() || appearPressed);
  }
  
} // class MyButtonModel
```

Answer (score 1):

you also need to override isArmed():

```
class MyButtonModel extends DefaultButtonModel
{
    private boolean appearPressed = true;

    @Override
    public boolean isPressed()
    {
        return super.isPressed() || appearPressed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isArmed() {
        return super.isArmed() || appearPressed;
    }
}
```